# Why is hasLayout always -1?

Tags: css, internet-explorer-6

I'm setting zoom:1; on some elements.  When I subsequently check the CSS using the developer tools in IE 6.0.29, I see that zoom:100% is there, but hasLayout is still -1.  Why isn't hasLayout being forced?

```
.album_thumbnail_outer_container {
  position: relative;
  height: 200px;
  width: 150px;
  border: solid black 1px;
  float:left;
  color: #628FDB;
  font-weight: bold;
  margin: 20px;
  background: #262626;
  text-align: center;
  *zoom:1;
}
```

Here's a screenshot of the properties:

http://www.zumodrive.com/share/COhNDQ2OT

Comment: My first call would be that IE6 hates you (and all of us). Could you maybe post some code? The zoom:1 should do the trick... You could also try setting the position as relative (just guessing here)

Comment: `hasLayout` is always reported as -1 for me, even though symptomatically the element in question *does* "have layout". Confuses me too.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Setting position relative can work but can also have other consequences so make sure you're aware of that. Also, only block elements can have layout so if you're trying this on an inline element it's not going to work.